# Creating Classic ASP cookie in PHP

Tags: php, cookies, asp-classic

I'm currently working on rewriting a project from classic ASP to PHP, my current dilemma is this. We have a login portal written in classic ASP that sets up a multidimensional cookie, after rewriting the page in PHP and setting up the cookie in the same format that classic ASP does, internal ASP pages don't seem to be recognizing the generated cookie, it knows it's there but can't seem to read it however PHP pages do, is there something I'm missing here?

Here's an example of what classic ASP has generated as a cookie from the original login portal:

```
manage%5Fbilling=1&startPage=%2Ftimesheet%2Ephp&manage%5Fpm=1&manage%5FCC=1&manage%5FcontactType=1&manage%5Fprojects=1&manage%5Fcontacts=1&manage%5Fcompanies=1&manage%5Ffiles=1&manage%5Flinks=1&manage%5Fusers=1&manage%5FSEO=1&manage%5Fexport=1&ID=58&lname=Ressler&dept=12134&email=shaun%40ezsolution%2Ecom&fname=Shaun&manage%5Ftasks=1&manage%5Fworkorders=1&manage%5Fnotes=1&ValidSession=true
```

And here's an example of what I tried to emulate using PHP to generate the same cookie:

```
ValidSession=true&fname=Zach&lname=Pickell&email=zach%40ezsolution%2Ecom&dept=12134&ID=65&manage%5Fusers=1&manage%5Fcompanies=1&manage%5Fcontacts=1&manage%5Fprojects=1&manage%5Flinks=1&manage%5FcontactType=1&manage%5Fexport=1&manage%5Fnotes=1&manage%5Ffiles=1&manage%5FSEO=1&manage%5FCC=1&manage%5Fworkorders=1&manage%5Fpm=1&manage%5Ftasks=1&manage%5Fbilling=1&startPage=%2Fdashboard%2Ephp
```

The ordering of the values are not the same but I don't know why that would have anything to do with it.

Much thanks!

Comment: Is your PHP running as a completely separate service (e.g. on a separate Apache server or similar), or is it running as an extension to IIS on the same server as the login portal?

Comment: It's running as an extension to IIS on the same server.

Comment: You *should* be able to see the session level variables in that case; (though I know less than a gnat about PHP) so if you can set them directly in PHP the session should pass across to your classic ASP app. In ASP you'd set the session variable something like: `Session("MY_VARIABLE") = 123` or `Session("MY_VARIABLE") = "text value"`.

Comment: Classic ASP pages can't read ASP.net session cookies and vice versa, so I expect the same is true with ASP/PHP, in which case you need to set your values in a page in each language.  I find zero size iframes and querystrings are the easiest way to do this

Comment: @John Good point. Mingan - Another idea would be to post the data via a hidden control and process it using the ASP page.